# How can you exclude fields in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Hello I would like to do something like:

```
Model.objects.all().values().exclude('id')
```

where the results are turned into a dictionary but excluding field 'id'. I know I could list out all the fields to bring into the dictionary but my model has close to 50 fields.  Is this possible in Django?

I have tried the following but it does not work:

```
Model.objects.all().defer('id').values()
```

Update (still does not work):

```
>>> University.objects.all().defer('state')[:2].values()
<QuerySet [{'id': 79, 'name': 'University of Alaska', 'email': 'alaska.edu', 'state': 'AK', 'userCount': 0}, {'id': 80, 'name': 'Alaska Christian College', 'email': 'alaskacc.edu', 'state': 'AK', 'userCount': 0}]>
>>> University.objects.defer('state')[:2].values()
<QuerySet [{'id': 79, 'name': 'University of Alaska', 'email': 'alaska.edu', 'state': 'AK', 'userCount': 0}, {'id': 80, 'name': 'Alaska Christian College', 'email': 'alaskacc.edu', 'state': 'AK', 'userCount': 0}]>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this:

```
YourModel.objects.all().defer('id')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `Model.objects.defer('id').values()` instead of `Model.objects.all().defer('id').values()`, but your code should work

Source [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#defer)

Answer (score 0):

Some fields in a model won’t be deferred, even if you ask for them. You can never defer the loading of the primary key.

I have tow propositions:

1)

```
test = Model.objects.values()
print(test[0])
for lolo in test:
    del lolo['id']
print(test[0])
```

2)

```
list_of_db_field = Model._meta.get_fields()
my_fields = []
for field in list_of_db_field:
      my_fields.append(field.name)
my_fields.remove('id')
test = Model.objects.values(*my_fields).last()
print(test)
```